# Avoiding Eigen's Memory allocation

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, eigen

I wanted to know if I could stop Eigen from new memory automatically and if I would get a speedup by doing so. I've attached a code snippet which is somewhat characteristic of what my program does.

```
#define EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC


#include <Eigen/Dense>


using namespace std;

using namespace Eigen;

#define UNCONST(t,c,uc) Eigen::MatrixBase<t> &uc = const_cast<Eigen::MatrixBase<t>&>(c);

template <typename Derived>
void multiply (const MatrixBase<Derived> &A, MatrixBase<Derived> const &const_C){
    Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>B;
    B.setOnes(500,500);
    
    UNCONST(Derived,const_C,C);

    Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(false);
    C = A*B;
    Eigen::internal::set_is_malloc_allowed(true);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic>A,C;
    A.setOnes(500,500);
    C.setOnes(500,500);
    multiply(A,C);
    
}
```

I compile this code in debug mode and when I execute it, I get the following error:

Assertion failed: (is_malloc_allowed() && "heap allocation is forbidden (EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC is defined and g_is_malloc_allowed is false)"), function check_that_malloc_is_allowed, file ../3rdparty/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h, line 189.

Is there a way I can switch off this memory allocation ?

I'm careful of making sure that matrices on the left hand side of an assignment have the correct dimensions. I deal with large matrices and I use functions like `multiply()` repeatedly. Would there be speedups in the code if I stopped these malloc calls ?

Comment: How would you allocate memory if not dynamically for large matrices? Most likely they won't fit on the stack.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more ? Ideally, I would not like to have new memory allocated in that statement because I'm never going to use a 'C' matrix that has the wrong dimensions for the expression  C=A*B

Comment: What I'm saying is that even if you manage to disable dynamic allocation, I don't see how you would allocate memory for a 500 x 500 matrix. It won't fit on the stack.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. My opening question has not been worded correctly. I should not have said "stop Eigen from allocating memory dynamically". I'll changed it to "stop Eigen from allocating new memory automatically".

Comment: @vsoftco The  matrices don't have to fit on the stack, you can allocate them statically as global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You you avoid the temporary for product using `noalias`:

```
C.noalias() = A * B;
```

As documented [there](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicWritingEfficientProductExpression.html).

Comment: Thank you! I tried that and I get a very similar error:                         Assertion failed: (is_malloc_allowed() && "heap allocation is forbidden (EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC is defined and g_is_malloc_allowed is false)"), function check_that_malloc_is_allowed, file ../3rdparty/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h, line 206.
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Right, I forgot to add that the noalias removes the temporary holding the result of A*B but there are still memory allocation going on to allocate some working space buffers. Those are needed to speedup the matrix product and make it cache friendly. You can omit them using a coefficient-wise product (`C.noalias()=A.lazyProduct(B)`) but for such matrix size, it will one or two orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this resolves my concerns. I profiled my code and it seemed that most of the time was being taken in malloc calls from Eigen. I'll add noalias() to my expressions, wherever applicable. Is that the best I can do shave off execution time ?

Comment: (1) noalias only makes sense for product expressions. (2) If malloc appears to be prohibitively expensive that probably means that your actual matrices are very small (like <16). If that's so and that their sizes are known at compile time, you can avoid any heap alloc using `Matrix<double,Rows,Cols>`. (3) Also if you have matrix/vector declarations within loops, try to move the declarations outside the loops.